# SwiftUI: Some buttons appear and some do not - MacOS menu bar app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a dynamic list which is created from an RSS feed. Each element contains the Title, Description and buttons that can open the url in a browser or copy  it to the clipboard. But for some reason some buttons appear and some not.

[image: screenshot of menubar app]

As you can see from the image on the left side the 2 buttons appear but after scrolling down the buttons have no text and they are a small block, instead of being like in the image of the left.

I've tried forcing a fixed size using `frame` but nothing changed. I tried applying GeometryReader to the buttons and HStack too but the position of them just changed to the center.

This is my view of the generated list:

```swift
 GeometryReader { gp in
    List(self.results, id: \.title) { item in
     VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(item.title).font(.headline).padding(.vertical, 5)
        Text(item.description).padding(.top, 5)
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                print("Hello")
            }){
                Text("Копирај линк")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                NSWorkspace.shared.open(item.article_url)
            }){
                Text("Отвори во прелистувач")
            }
        }
     }.frame(width: gp.size.width)
   }
}
```

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.6. Would you prepare complete standalone demo?

Comment: @Asperi what should one standalone demo look like?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Asperi I upgraded to the lateset MacOS version and it fixed it :D. I guess a SwiftUI bug?